# Periodic communication using threads and GUI

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I need to make a GUI using QT that will communicate with an embedded software through a serial port. The user will set a communication frequency and when they click start, the GUI will send periodic control messages to the embedded sw.

The embedded sw responds to each message with a response containing its status info, which is shown on the screen via some display widgets.

Most of the info is not time critical (I mean the screen does not need to be updated at each incoming and outgoing message) However, the command and feedback position information need to be fetched from every message and be plotted on the screen so that no position data is lost.

Firstly, I coded the entire application without using any threads, but when I run it at 100 Hz for example the GUI starts to freeze or miss some of the messages. So I decided to create a seperate thread that will handle the communication. It's my first time trying to use threads in QT and I only have some theoretical knowledge regarding threading.

I checked all of the examples that uses threads, but I couldn't find one that carries on both a **periodic** task (sending messages) and a **triggered** task (receiving messages). I do not want to wait for the response after sending the message, since it sometimes takes longer for the response to arrive than the communication period.

My idea was to use two two mutexes in the thread's run function, and the thread calls tryLock on each mutex to send or receive a message.

```
class CommunicationThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CommunicationThread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    
    QMutex sendMutex;
    
    QMutex receiveMutex;
    
    QTimer *SendControlCommand_Timer;
    
    QSerialPort *serialPort;
    
    Communication_Packets_st *commManager_s; // the communication library struct 
    
    double SendAngle_d;
    
    double ReceiveAngle_d;
    
    uint32 LastSendIndex_u32 = 0;
    
    double periodSec_d;

private slots:

    void MessageReceived_Slot();

    void SendControlCommand_Slot();
    
}


void CommunicationThread::run()
{
    forever {
        if(sendMutex.tryLock())
        {

            //calculate the sendAngle here and add it to the graph, the other fields of the structure will be filled by the main thread with a slower frequency
            //...
            
            CommandGraph->addData(LastSendIndex_u32*periodSec_d,SendAngle_d);
            LastSendIndex_u32++;
            
            commManager_s->ControlCommandPacket_s.CommandAngle_i32 =
                    static_cast<int32>(SendAngle_d * COMMAND_ANGLE_MULTIPLIER);
            
            Comm_SendControlCommand(commManager_s); //Function that serializes data and sends the message
            sendMutex.lock();
        }
        if(receiveMutex.tryLock())
        {
            QByteArray ReceiveBuffer_ba;
            quint32 length_u32;

            if(serialPort->bytesAvailable())
            {
                ReceiveBuffer_ba.append(serialPort->readAll());
            }
            Comm_PacketParser(commManager_s); //Function that parses the serial message and fills the commManager_s struct.
            //Put the feedback angle in the plot here so no data is lost, the other fields of the received message will be read and displayed by the main thread with a slower frequency
            ReceiveAngle_d = static_cast<double>
                (commManager_s->ControlCommandResponsePacket_s.AxisAngle_i32) * FEEDBACK_ANGLE_MULTIPLIER;
            
        }
    }
}
```

I connected the readyRead signal of the serial port to a slot that unlocks the receiveMutex. And the sendMutex is unlocked in the SendControlCommand_Slot() triggered by the SendControlCommand_Timer's timeout signal.
Of course I will use mutexes that will protect the shared data, but also using these two mutexes is the only idea I could come up with to implement this periodic and triggered tasks that needs to be carried out by the same thread.

To sum up, my question is this:
What is the correct way of structuring this communication thread that will read and write data from/to the serial port, using a single instance of the communication library structure that will also be used by the main thread?

Comment: The GUI froze because you need to process events (`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`) while you are waiting. But... why don't you simply use a `QTimer` and connect its `timeout()` signal to a slot that sends your control messages ?

Comment: Using QTimer is what I did in the first place, but it seems not to be working very well. The screen freezes often and my application does not receive some messages now and then. I compared the number of messages I received to the number of messages the embedded sw sent, the result showed up to be around 10% messages being lost. 
I tried using both readyRead signal and polling the serial port with a timer that has 0 period, there wasn't much of a difference.

Comment: Using QCoreApplication::processEvents() did not occur to me though, I will try it, thanks.

Comment: *takes longer for the response to arrive than the communication period* doesn't make much sense to me if the polling period is more frequent than the obtainable replies. I wouldn't send a new polling message without receiving the reply of the previous one.

Comment: @neko I was more thinking of using `QTimer` to handle the periodic send. The polling for waiting to the response is just a `while` loop in which you call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` to not have the GUI freezing while you wait until there are bytes available to read. And it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the client is losing packets on the computer and not on the connected device?

You can use a USB -> UART adapter instead of a real device by connecting the TX & RX pins with a jumper for testing.

I wrote an example without a separate thread and without using `QCoreApplication :: processEvents ()`.

I ran this example and didn't lose any packages.

Although the reading lagged noticeably behind the transmission.

[example project](https://github.com/kolod/stackoverflow/tree/main/69403884/example)

You can also look at [this](https://github.com/kolod/Arduino-PPM-Generator) project of mine. It uses the Modbus communication protocol.

Comment: I am sure, we debug the embedded device and make it count how many messages & sent. They turn out to be equal to my software's sent messages count. But my software's received message count lags behind those three numbers.

Comment: And thanks a lot for the code, I am currently out of office but will look into it as soon as I get back

Comment: I cannot do the loopback test thing though, since the command and response messages are very different from each other and I didn't teach my software to interpret the control message. (Control message is 13 bytes, Response message is 27 bytes)